# Передать в функцию класс аргументом? JS

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли передать в функцию класс или переменную (название класса) так чтобы подставить в этот код? (CLASSNAME)

```
const reRenderEl = (targetId, 'CLASSNAME') => {
    const mainContent = document.getElementById(targetId);
    mainContent.innerHTML = '';
    const allUsersItem = new 'CLASSNAME'(targetId);
}
```

Comment: Зачем передавать название класса, если можно передать сам класс?

Comment: хороший вопрос, сейчас когда я так сделал, все заработало, до этого - нет, подумал что класс нельзя передать, поэтому начал придумывать костыли с названием класса, спасибо большое за помощь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты можешь передавать классы, как аргументы.
Значит, можешь либо передавать классы в функцию "как есть".
Или создать коллекцию Имя-Класс и по имени получать класс.

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, lastname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lastname = lastname;
  }
  sayHi() {
    console.log(this.name, this.lastname);
  }
};

class Dog {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  bark() {
    console.log(this.name + " say: Wow! Wow!");
  }
};

const Classes = {"USER": User, "DOG": Dog};

function doSmth(name, lastname, className) {
  const user = new Classes[className](name, lastname);
  user.sayHi();
}

doSmth("Foo", "Bar", "USER");
```

Comment: Только надо что-то придумать с `className`, чтобы не перепутать его с CSS-классом)

Answer (score 0):

Можно передавайте функцию. В параметре. Функцию можно вызвать с оператором new. А параметры в js резиновые можете передавать.

```
const reRenderEl = (targetId,  func) => {
    const allUsersItem = new func(targetId);
}

function testFunc(arg) {
   console.log(arg);
}

reRender(12345, testFunc);
```

Comment: Уже не любую. Стрелочную нельзя. Метод класса нельзя 

Comment: Эт то понятно что не из всех функций можно. Ну пример то корректный